# Duplicated entry from blockquotes and octavo class

Tags: csquotes, enotez, octavo

The following code generates a duplicated entry in glossary, even though it is defined just once.

It is not necessary to run makeindex. Just pdflatex twice.

The package `csquotes` was used.
The problem appeared after I used `enotez`.

Can this be fixed or it is a bug?

```
\documentclass[foolscap,10pt,openright]{octavo}
%Preamble
\makeatletter
%\def\input@path{{./}{./octavo}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{bibref,autind}

%Bibliografia
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{brazil} 
\setbtxfallbacklanguage{portuguese}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %For chemical equations
\usepackage{lettrine}

% Optical margins, kerning etc.
\usepackage[
  activate={true,nocompatibility},
  final,
  tracking=true,
  kerning=true,
  spacing=true,
  babel=true,
]{microtype} 
%\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{enotez}

\usepackage[
  autostyle=false,
  csdisplay=true,
  threshold=1,
  thresholdtype=words,
  csdisplay=true,
]{csquotes}

% Decrease font size when quoting 
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\smaller}

%Insert () for endnotes
\renewcommand\enmark{\textsuperscript{(\theenmark)}}
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
 {
  heading = \chapter{Glossário},
  notes-sep = 0pt,
  format = \normalfont,
  number = \textsuperscript{(#1)}
 }

\newcommand{\nomedepgm}[1]{\textsf{\smaller #1}}% Used with program names

% Nice for pages like \putoncenter{The end}
\newcommand{\putoncenter}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \scshape #1
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
}

% New index
\newindex{idenomes}{ndx}{nnx}{\'{I}ndice de nomes}
%\index[idenomes]{John7 Doe1}

% fix the headers
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

\newcommand*{\abbrev}[1]{\textls[40]{\textsc{#1}}}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Prefácio}


This text contains both 
endnotes\endnote{\emph{End notes}, in this specific case, is supposed to be a glossary.} and 
footnotes\footnote{This is a footnote, not an end note.}.
I cannot distinguish one from another.

Here comes some dummy text with an endnote:%:
\blockquote{%
This is latin\endnote{\emph{Latin} is an old language.}:
\lipsum[75]
}

Now go to the glossary and you will see the duplicated entry generated from within the blockquote.

I'll add just some dummy text and another endnote%
\endnote{\emph{Lorem ipsum} is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.}.
This one is correct, not duplicated.


\cleardoublepage
\backmatter

%Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

%I used a kind of glossary, but like a chapter
\printendnotes[custom]

% Here comes a name index
\printindex[idenomes]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following shortened MWE reproduces the issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enotez}
\renewcommand*\enotezwritemark[1]{\textsuperscript{(#1)}}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
endnote\endnote{End note one.} and 
footnotes\footnote{Regular footnote one.}.

Here comes some dummy text with an endnote:
\blockquote{%
Footnote\footnote{Single footnote} endnote\endnote{Double endnote}
\lipsum[75]}

Fn\footnote{Footnote two}
En\endnote{Endnote three}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll let the [`csquotes` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) explain why that happens (pp. 37-38):

> The block quotation facilities need to typeset all quotations twice. The first pass is required to measure the length of the quotation. The actual typesetting takes place on the second pass, in a format depending on the result of the first one.

`csquotes` takes some measures to avoid unwanted side-effects of effectively executing the same code twice, but not all unwanted side-effects can be avoided that way.

On a quick first look I could not find out which bits of `enotez`' implementation cause its commands to not be reset by `csquotes` protection measures.

In situations like these you can use `\BlockquoteDisable` to temporarily disable the offending command (p. 38 of the `csquotes` documentation).

> If you observe any malfunctions related to the trial pass (for example, if counters are incremented twice or if an item appears twice in a list), use `\BlockquoteDisable` to redefine or disable the affected command temporarily.

```
\BlockquoteDisable{%
  \renewcommand{\endnote}[2][]{}%
}
```

This means that `\endnote` will simply be ignored in the first measuring pass of `blockquote`. And indeed with those lines added to the MWE we obtain

[image]

---

*edit*

From the `csquotes` manual

> In order to prevent any side-effects of the first (trial) pass, the `csquotes` package (1) performs the first pass inside a group, (2) employs checkpointing to freeze all LaTeX counters, and (3) sets `\if@filesw` to false. However, it can not prevent side-effects caused by commands that (1) make any global assignments which are not overwritten on the second pass (for example, by way of `\g@addto@macro`), (2) increment counters globally in a way that circumvents LaTeX’s counter commands, or (3) do not check `\if@filesw` every time they are about to write to an auxiliary file.

It turns out that `enotez` does not obey `\if@filesw` when it writes to the `.aux` file. So the issue could alternatively be solved with

```
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_save_note:nnnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  { \if@filesw\iow_now:Nn \@auxout { \enotez@note {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} {#6} {#7} }\fi }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

In that case a global internal integer is still stepped up and so a number is skipped, but that should not have problematic consequences.

I have opened an issue at the `enotez` bugtracker (https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/issues/13/should-endnotes-obey-if-filesw) to ask whether or not it would be useful to have `enotez` obey `\if@filesw`.